# Find corresponding values in other dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2

df2:
   b  c
0  0  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
```

Now I want to add a new column d to df1, which contains the value of df2.c, when df1.a == df2.b. I.e. the result should be this:

```
   a d
0  0 5
1  1 nan
2  2 6
```

I tried: `df1.loc[:, 'd'] = df2.loc[df2.b.eq(df1.a), 'c']`,
which does not work. Could you explain to me why not? I am assuming sth with the indices.
Further, how can I achieve what I want? Apply, concat ... ?
Thanks!

Edit:
In my concrete application case I can encounter duplicates, e.g.:

```
df1:
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2

df2:
   b  c
0  0  5
1  0  6
2  3  7
```

I now want to assign to a new column df1.d a list of all values of df2.c, where df2.b == df1.a, i.e.:

```
   a d
0  0 [5, 6]
1  1 nan
2  2 nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `merge` (pandas is index and column sensitive , your df1 and df2 link key is a and b, not the index , when you are using .loc it is assuming index assign)

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on='a',right_on='b',how='left').drop('b',1).rename(columns={'c':'d'})
Out[136]: 
   a    d
0  0  5.0
1  1  NaN
2  2  6.0
```

Or `map`

```
df1['d']=df1.a.map(df2.set_index('b').c)
df1
Out[142]: 
   a    d
0  0  5.0
1  1  NaN
2  2  6.0
```

If more columns

```
df1=df1.set_index('a')
df2=df2.set_index('b')

df1.join(df2)
Out[157]: 
     d    c
a          
0  5.0  5.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  6.0  6.0
```

Update

```
df1.a.map(df2.groupby('b').c.apply(list))
Out[205]: 
0    [5, 6]
1       NaN
2       NaN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, that looks good. How coudld I select multple columns in the map approach?

Comment: @Gemini what you mean multiple columns?

Comment: selecting columns c and possibly more which are existing in df2

Comment: And what if, in df2 there are multiple rows with the same b values, i.e. I want to add a list of all these to df1?

Comment: @Gemini can you modify your question ?